# Create a blog then display it on my website

Tags: web, frontend, blogs

so here is the thing: I'm creating a website and the client ask for a blog. So I create the blog on blogger.

Next, the client wants that his blog feed to be displayed on the website. For exemple:

[here is my code. The client wants the posts of the blog to be displayed in the section element with the class 'blog'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrQng.png)

My question is: how can I do it?

I already tried to use  but is not that good.  Also, whatenever the client publish a new post that post need to be entered in the section.

Any ideias how to do this for free?

Thanks

I already tried to use , but the result is not good.